# Alert Logs for ADB-S instance?

Tags: logging, oracle-autonomous-db

Can users get access to the alert log for their Autonomous Database on Shared Infrastructure instance - even if in some truncated / redacted form?

Answer (score 1):

Only Oracle's Cloud Operations have access to the physical alert logs on disk. Users can run queries against the view - v$diag_alert_ext view

e.g.:

```
select ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP, INST_ID, CON_ID, PROCESS_ID, message_text, MESSAGE_ARGUMENTS from V$DIAG_ALERT_EXT where ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP > sysdate - 1;

select MESSAGE_TEXT from v$diag_alert_ext where component_id like '%rdbms%' order by ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP;
```

*Ref - I am a product manager on the Oracle Autonomous Database*